# What is this height? (a list under the SliverAppBar)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `SliverAppBar`. I have a list just below. But although I don't give a height, when the list starts, there is  [an empty height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNqY2.jpg) at the beginning. Why? Is the reason `SliverToBoxAdapter`?

Full code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5,
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            snap: false,
            elevation: 0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                title: Text('Title',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    )),
                background: Image.network(
                  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                    color: Colors.red),
                child: ListView(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                      Text("text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),),
                    ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the widget inspector say?

Comment: Yes the problem appears in `ListView` .  One of the trees under it is like this: SliverPadding -> padding: EdgeInsets (0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0). Can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove padding of ListView with this:

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
    context: context,
    removeTop: true,
    child: ListView.builder(
     .......
    )
  )
```